# Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter (groovy-3.0.7)

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to install Groovy on Windows 10 manually.
And I keep receiving the following error.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter

What I did is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>Setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %java_home%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2

C:\WINDOWS\system32>Md "C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>move "C:\temp\groovy-3.0.7" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>Setx GROOVY_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\groovy-3.0.7\src"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\groovy-3.0.7\src\bin";%PATH%
```

And when I type "groovysh"

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>groovysh
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter
```

I am not sure what I have missed.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone points out my mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the groovy folder from? If you downloaded it from github you'll have to run gradle bootstrap before using it

Comment: Hi,  I downloaded it from https://groovy-lang.org/install.html and select "Source Release".

Comment: I think you should have selected the binary release, which will have all those files included

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am wondering what is the difference between binary release and source release.

Comment: Source release is literally the source code to Groovy. If you want to use it you have to build/compile it, which is not for novices. It is what open source means. If you just want to us it, download the binary release. Get the 3.0.8 windows installer [here](https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-windows-installer/groovy-3.0.8/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback

Comment: Any solution to this thread?

Comment: Installing from .msi fixed it for me. I removed the groovy environment variables which i manually set. And then installed from msi. The Installation set the env variables. Thanks @ou_ryperd